# Adding text into .tex file with python

Tags: python, latex

**How can I read .tex file, and save it's content into string using python?**

I was searching for the solution on the internet, but I couldn't find anything useful.

I'm using Windows not Linux.

What I managed to do is:

```
f = open("xxx.tex","a")

f.write('This is a test\n')
```

However **f** is a object right now, not a string, if I'm right.

Comment: `This is a test\n` is a string... so you are working with strings...

Comment: This is however  the content of f is not. This is a test was just a test to see if i can write into this file.

Comment: You wish to read from a file or write to a file?

Comment: Both first i have to open a file and then find the right place in file to write some new text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
texdoc = []  # a list of string representing the latex document in python

# read the .tex file, and modify the lines
with open('test.tex') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        texdoc.append(line.replace('width=.5\\textwidth', 'width=.9\\textwidth'))

# write back the new document
with open('test.tex', 'w') as fout:
    for i in range(len(texdoc)):
        fout.write(texdoc[i])
```

or like this (could be trickier):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import fileinput

# inplace=True means that standard output is directed to the input file
for line in fileinput.input('test.tex', inplace=True):
    print(line.replace('width=.5\\textwidth', 'width=.9\\textwidth'), end=' ')))
```